# how to run springboot app in visual studio code? is it possible or not?

Tags: spring-boot, visual-studio-code

[image]

1. Add plugin and run the spring boot application

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: Here is an article on how to setup VS Code for spring boot development: https://jonamlabs.com/how-to-setup-visual-studio-code-for-spring-boot-development/

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Install Apache maven in your system. Make sure that the path/maven/bin directory is available in your system's PATH environment variable.
2. open terminal inside vs code(press Ctrl + `)
3. Execute the following command : I used bash terminal for it

   **./mvnw spring-boot:run**

Comment: What if it is not maven, it is gradle?

Comment: @AnonymousCreator It's `./gradlew bootRun`

Comment: Does this method allow vscode to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

The @Vikey solution does note feature debugging, I think. You you should use an integrated solution, like an extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-spring-boot-dashboard

[image]

[image]