# How to run a Spring Boot maven project in VSCode and how to config the base url of a spring boot web application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I have a Maven project which I need to run from VSCode. Right now the way I do it is:

1. Open the project folder in VSCode. Edit the java, js, html files etc.
2. Start my tomcat by running `bin/startup.sh; tail -f logs/* ;` in the apache tomcat's directory.
3. Open terminal in the project directory and run `mvn clean install -DskipTests`.
4. Then run `cp /Users/path-to-my-project/target/myWebApp.war ~/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/` to copy the war file into the tomcat's webapp directory.

After which I can access my web application at localhost:8080/myWebApp.

Is it possible to do all of this in one click (or command) in VSCode. I know it can be done in Eclipse or IntelliJ but I want to work with VSCode.

I have installed the Spring Boot Extension Pack and Java Extension Pack in VSCode. I am just confused on how to setup the path to my tomcat, build the project and then copy the war file to the tomcat webapps folder.

Comment: Why do you want to generate a war package and copy it to tomcat webapp folder? To make your webapp visitable, just `Ctrl+\`` to get a terminal, and then `mvnw spring-boot:run`

Comment: Thats sweet, it worked. Question: in the application there is a suffix after the locahost:8080. So something like localhost:8080/mywebapp/...rest of the url. With the above method everything works but I loose that web app name suffix. Any idea how I can get it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do all of this in one click (or command) in VSCode. I know it can be done in Eclipse or IntelliJ but I want to work with VSCode.

To make your webapp visitable, just type:

```
Ctrl+`
```

in the VS Code to get a terminal, and then type:

```
mvnw spring-boot:run
```

> in the application there is a suffix after the locahost:8080. So something like localhost:8080/mywebapp/...rest of the url. With the above method everything works but I loose that web app name suffix. Any idea how I can get it back?

In your `application.properties` file(in the `src/main/resources` folder in your spring boot project), add below line(for Spring boot v2.0.5):

```
server.servlet.context-path=/mywebapp
```

For older version, you may need:

```
server.contextPath=/mywebapp
```

---

See these links for reference:

[How to set base url for rest in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927937/how-to-set-base-url-for-rest-in-spring-boot)

[What is the purpose of mvnw and mvnw.cmd files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723833/what-is-the-purpose-of-mvnw-and-mvnw-cmd-files)

[how to run springboot app in visual studio code? is it possible or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201163/how-to-run-springboot-app-in-visual-studio-code-is-it-possible-or-not)